# Android Preferences: Dependencies

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to use revert dependencies?

```
<Preference android:key="test"
    android:title="@string/test" android:summary="@string/test_summary"
    android:dependency="dependOn" />
```

In this example the test preference is shown if dependOn is selected, but i want it the other way round.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591901/how-to-do-opposite-of-of-preference-attribute-androiddependency/3591956#3591956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place a listener on the dependOn checkbox and enable the test preference as dependOn becomes selected.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: thanks, that would have been my solution too. But i tought there was also a easier way to that it.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually achieve this by setting:

```
android:disableDependentsState="true"
```

in your dependOn definition.