# Android: Reverse Preference dependencies

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do opposite of of preference attribute android:dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591901/how-to-do-opposite-of-of-preference-attribute-androiddependency)

In a PreferenceActivity, we can define Preferences with XML code. One of these is:

```
android:dependency
```

This can be used to set a preference to only be sensitive if a checkbox or similar is enabled. However, is there a way to set up the screen so that preferences are available only if a certain box is *not* checked - effectively the opposite of the above?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591901/how-to-do-opposite-of-of-preference-attribute-androiddependency)